# How to use torch custom dataset with fastai data loaders

Tags: pytorch, torch, fast-ai, dataloader

I created a custom torch dataset and specified 2 required methods: `__getitem__` and `__len__`. Then I created two torch data loaders:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

and I wanted to use them with `fastai`, so I tried to run:

```
from fastai.vision.data import DataLoaders
dls = vision.data.DataLoaders(train_loader, valid_loader)
from fastai.vision.learner import cnn_learner, error_rate
learner_original = cnn_learner(dls, models.resnet34, metrics=error_rate, pretrained=True)
```

However, this gives me an error:

> AttributeError: 'DataLoader' object has no attribute 'after_batch'

What's wrong with my setup? Should torch dataset have another attribute to make it compatible with fastai DataLoaders?